# been trying to find this font desperately, if you know which one it is, that'd be awesome!

Tags: fonts

[image] any idea what it could be?????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [Mom's Typewriter](https://www.dafont.com/moms-typewriter.font?psize=l&text=spider) font:

[image]

Once you make it curved, it would be 'distorted' like your reference:

[image]

Comment: wow. you're the goat! . thanks‼️ so much